# os.system not running in same subshell

Tags: android, python, python-3.x

I'm trying to build android using my script. Now in my build's root folder, I'm executing the following:

```
os.system("source build/envsetup.sh")
os.system("choosecombo 1 <chipsetname> <buildtype>")
os.system("make -j32")
```

and I even tried this:

```
os.system("source build/envsetup.sh;choosecombo 1 <chipsetname> <buildtype>;make -j32")
```

Any idea where am I wrong?

I know that os.system executes in a new subshell. Thus, shouldn't it execute the 2nd option in the same subshell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each call to os.system is done in a NEW subshell, so treat each call as an independant call, you can't rely on something done before to (like sourcing a shell script) to do something else.

If the second way works in a standard shell, it should work in an `os.system` call.

Comment: any workaround for this? the second one works fine in a standard shell, but not in os.system(). That's the confusing part

Comment: There was no error as such but on Linux, I lost my settings after every call of os.system(). I used subprocess.call(<all 3 statements here">seperated by ;) and it worked.